# Python Loop Understanding

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, output

I'm self learning Python, and I've been stuck on this loop problem for a while. I wrote a script to extract Data every hour about stock prices, but for each hour of data I have manually created new variables to hold my new data.

- Is there a loop that will do this for me without having to create a new line of variables for each run?
- and can that loop create a text file that has a differing name?      (for example:  Txtfile1.txt ,  Txtfile2.txt...)

Code example attached below:

```
 R = requests.get("https://api.website.com/v1/....")
 data = R.json()

for x in data:
       ticker = x['symbol']
       cost = x['price_usd']

print (ticker + "\t:" + cost)
with open('Marketcap.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2)

time.sleep(3600)


R2 = requests.get("https://api.website.com/v1/....")
data2 = R2.json()

for y in data2:

        ticker2 = y['symbol']
        cost2 = y['price_usd']

print(ticker2  +":\t" + cost2)

with open('Marketcap2.txt', 'w') as outfile2:
    json.dump(data2, outfile2, indent=2)

time.sleep(3600)
```

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you could use a *list*?

Comment: And you can reuse the same variable names...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I want to help but I don't really understand what you want to do. I suggest you set aside concepts like "loops" for a moment and describe the purpose of your program in more detail. You say you are downloading stock data. Then what do you want to do with this data? Think of this process like building a house. You start with a blueprint before you ever worry about whether to use a hammer or a screwdriver. `for` loops are one of many tools that we use as a programmer. They are like the hammer, screwdriver, or saw of a house builder.

Comment: But you need an overall blueprint before you can even decide what the appropriate tools are for individual parts of the program.

Comment: With that said, I suggest that you learn about functions. They will help you write code that is easily reused like you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.  I'm currently reading up on lists and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just enclose whatever it is you are iteratively repeating in a for loop (Therefore you will get a nested `for` loop)

If you have a set amount of times you want to run your data extracting program, say 12, then use this:

```
r = requests.get("https://api.website.com/v1/....")
data = r.json()

for i in range(12):
    for x in data:

        ticker = x['symbol']
        cost = x['price_usd']

        print(ticker + ":\t", cost)
        # define a new name for our variable:
        name = 'Marketcap{}.txt'.format(i)

        with open(name, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2)

    time.sleep(3600)
```

If you would like to use it "forever", there is a built-in library called `itertools` that will let you use the `for` function indefinitely for incrementing:

```
from itertools import count

for i in count(0):
    for x in data:

        ticker = x['symbol']
        cost = x['price_usd']

        print(ticker  + ":\t", cost)
        name = 'Marketcap{}.txt'.format(i)

        with open(name, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2)

    time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: Wow I learned alot from your response.    I have to practice understanding  ' For loops '  and learning more about Itertools.    I'm told   the best way to learn a language is through purpose driven projects & this is one of mine.

Thanks for the response